# Can image transforms decrease performance?

Tags: image-transforms, performance

If I have a site that will eventually have thousands of product images on it, would using image transforms slow things down?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope. Once a transform has been generated once, Craft remembers that, and saves it right in your asset source. Future page loads will get a direct URL to that generated image, so it gets loaded via your webserver (or S3, etc.) directly. No PHP involved.

Comment: Then you’ll start getting 404s on that image, since Craft won’t be aware that the file doesn’t exist anymore. You can always clear your craft_assettransformindex table though, which is where Craft stores its records of all generated transforms.

Comment: What happens if that image got deleted?

Comment: Sorry I deleted that comment because I thought Brad made the race.. But then your very satisfying answer popped up :)

Comment: I just thought of something- what if Google PageSpeed has grabbed the images after the first time and is now serving them?

Answer (score 8):

For all practical purposes, no.  The performance hit for images transforms happens the first time the transform is requested and generated.  After that, the images are served as a normal file that your web server can serve up as quickly as any other file.

Comment: It's a Pixel & Tonic [answer duel](http://youtu.be/AphxyjrH4SE)!

Comment: Just so we're clear here... I'm James T. Kirk.

Comment: What happens if that image got deleted?

Comment: In what context?  The transformed image?  The source image?

Comment: The transformed image is missing, does this trigger another transform? If yes, is there any script that initializes this and doesn't that take performance?

Comment: So I just request them myself and handle it.